Premiere SDK. Is it possible to add an alpha matte through premiere script?
I'm working on a project which should create a dynamic mask of the object(s) of focus (or mimic one). So far, I have the functionality to get the data of coordinates of pixels corresponding to that object from the Lucas-Kanade method. Basically, I have a two-color video, one color the dynamic "mask" of the object and the other of the background. Likewise, I have this data as a binary matrix.
Does anyone know the method to create an alpha matte in premiere script like you can do in AE. I've given up on an actual mask as I don't know of any file types which can support transparency. If it's not possible, perhaps there is a better method to mimic a mask; that'd be even better.
I've checked the guide and dug through what I could of the sample (A lot is a lot to follow honestly, I'm still new to adobe scripting), and I'm at somewhat of an impasse. Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you
